# Section number in list of theorem

Tags: ntheorem

I would like to insert the section number in the list of theorems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{listeThm}{\textsc{thm}}

\begin{document}

\section{AA}
\addtotheoremfile[listeThm]{\bfseries La section \thesection}
\begin{listeThm} Theo A1 \end{listeThm}
\begin{listeThm} Theo A2 \end{listeThm}
\begin{listeThm} Theo A3 \end{listeThm}

\section{BB}
\addtotheoremfile[listeThm]{\bfseries La section \thesection}
\begin{listeThm} Theo B1 \end{listeThm}
\begin{listeThm} Theo B2 \end{listeThm}

\section{CC}
\addtotheoremfile[listeThm]{\bfseries La section \thesection}
\begin{listeThm} Theo C \end{listeThm}

\theoremlisttype{allname}
\listtheorems{listeThm}

\end{document}
```

All I get is the last section which is repeated. What am I doing wrong?

```
La section 3
thm 1 ................................ 1
thm 2 ................................ 1
thm 3 ................................ 1

La section 3
thm 4 ................................ 1
thm 5 ................................ 1

La section 3
thm 6 ................................ 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use cross-references:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{listeThm}{\textsc{thm}}

\begin{document}

\section{AA}\label{sec-AA}
\addtotheoremfile[listeThm]{\bfseries La section \ref{sec-AA}}
\begin{listeThm} Theo A1 \end{listeThm}
\begin{listeThm} Theo A2 \end{listeThm}
\begin{listeThm} Theo A3 \end{listeThm}

\section{BB}\label{sec-BB}
\addtotheoremfile[listeThm]{\bfseries La section \ref{sec-BB}}
\begin{listeThm} Theo B1 \end{listeThm}
\begin{listeThm} Theo B2 \end{listeThm}

\section{CC}\label{sec-CC}
\addtotheoremfile[listeThm]{\bfseries La section \ref{sec-CC}}
\begin{listeThm} Theo C \end{listeThm}

\theoremlisttype{allname}
\listtheorems{listeThm}

\end{document}
```

[image]